# After running npm run dist the dist folder gets locked

Tags: windows-10, directory, electron-builder

I am trying to use electron-builder and when I do 'npm run dist' I can get the exe files I wanted in the dist folder

However, after this, the dist folderis locked and cannot be erased or its name changed. When trying to do this the message that a program is using the folder appears.
Anybody has had the same problem??

Comment: What version of electron-builder? I had that issue (on OSX) and it was resolved by upgrading to a later version (20.39.0). I had to uninstall and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the process kept running by going to Task Manager details. I am guessing the application does not handle well when the window is closed, therefore the application does not terminate resources. Killing the running application permits the folder to be operated